# Can you solve it?

Tags: function, pointers

Define a C function void swapItems (int *a, int i, int j) that inter- exchange the array elements at index i and j. For a [] = {6,7,8,2,3}, a call to swapItems (a,1,3) makes a [] = {6,2,8,7, 3}.

Comment: As shared on your other question, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You only posted your assignment, with no work, and then left it to the Community to solve for you (and that's not how this site works).

Answer (score 0):

I created a temporary variable to swap the array elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swapItems(int*, int, int);
void printItems(int[], int);

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 6, 7, 8, 2, 3 };
    
    swapItems(a, 1, 3);
    printItems(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}

void swapItems(int* a, int i, int j)
{
    int temporary = a[i];
    
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temporary;
}

void printItems(int a[], int size_n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output of this code is 6, 2, 8, 7, 3.

Comment: Please don't post an answer to something like this. The OP only posted the assignment, showing no work (you likely just submitted a classroom assignment for them). Also note that they've now posted a 2nd assignment the exact same way, and this is not what this site is for (having people solve assignments without doing any work).